# Highcharts - Selection Event Modify Options

Tags: highcharts

This is my selection event handler in my code which I am for specific zoom timezones as you can see. What I am trying to achieve is to change the xAxis labels based on the zoom. Currently the following code does not work but I can not seem to find a solution to this problem online. Any thought?

Real question would be how can I alter highchart options through events. From the event parameter in the function I can access information but I can not change it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two aproach, the first with changing inside event chart.redraw() will be called every time when chart is redrawn, for testing I added fired from a button.

```
  redraw: function() {
    let chart = this;
    console.log(chart);
    chart.xAxis[0].userMax = 8;
    chart.xAxis[0].userMin = 2;
  },
```

The next way is to update the axis object with a new set of userMax and userMin options.

```
  chart.xAxis[0].update({
    userMax: 8,
    userMin: 2
  }, true);
```

Live demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fcsd9hyo/

API References:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update